# Is it necessary to pass 'passHref' to NextJS <Link> having a Semantic UI React as its child component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, semantic-ui-react

I've been reading the nextjs docs and it says in [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-function-component) that:

> If the child of `Link` is a function component, in addition to using
> `passHref`, you must wrap the component in `React.forwardRef`:

I'm new to using Semantic UI React so I'm not really sure if I need to do this and more importantly **how** to do this. I'm concerned about this because just before the quoted lines above, the docs says [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-custom-component-that-wraps-an-a-tag) that:

> Without this (the passHref), the  tag will not have the href attribute, which
> might hurt your site’s SEO.

I can pass the `passHref` like this:

```
<Link href='/posts' passHref>
  <Button>See Posts</Button>
</Link>
```

But the problem is that I don't think that we can wrap a component from Semantic UI with the `React.forwardRef` since it's just imported. So my questions are:

- Is it just fine to let this be?
- Or is there a workaround for this to "not hurt" my site's SEO?

Comment: The `next/link` component is meant to either wrap an `<a>` tag or a component which itself wraps an `<a>` tag. In your scenario, the `Button` component from Semantic UI is neither. If you want to use a `Link` there, you'd have to add an `<a>` as a direct child to it (which would be the parent of `Button`). The question then is, why would you want a button wrapped in an anchor? Shouldn't it be one or the other?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes . The nextJs Documentation states if your child is not just an  tag but a functional or class component then the passHref is needed. Make sure to pass it whenever you use a react component as a child

Answer (score 1):

You need passHref only with some tags, here is [an example](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-custom-component-that-wraps-an-a-tag).  is not about SEO, and your quote is about "If your  does not have passHref attribute and has  child, your SEO might be broken".

Just create 2 pages  with passHref and without, and check the pages, for example, with LIghthouse of chrome or any other tool. Also, check the DOM, you will see, no changes in SEO directly. (ofc if child components are html or even react components with no "required" href property.)

Comment: Yes but it clearly states here (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-function-component) that **If the child of Link is a function component, in addition to using passHref.** Meaning, we should pass `passHref` if using a function component, not only when using other HTML tags.

Answer (score -1):

yes, in some cases you need to do the following according to the Nextjs documentation:

```
function NavLink({ href, name }) {
  // Must add passHref to Link
  return (
    <Link href={href} passHref>
      <RedLink>{name}</RedLink>
    </Link>
  )
}
```