# Next.js <a> tag vs passHref

Tags: next.js

Can someone explain to me the difference between using passHref and using an anchor tag when setting up links between pages in Next.js?

E.g. what is the difference between:

```
<Link href={`/posts/${post.id}`} passHref>
  <h2>
    {post.id} {post.title}
  </h2>
</Link>
```

and

```
<Link href={`/posts/${post.id}`}>
  <a>
    {post.id} {post.title}
  </a>
</Link>
```

I tried reading about it in the documentation but could not seem to find the answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68983089/is-it-necessary-to-pass-passhref-to-nextjs-link-having-a-semantic-ui-react-a

This question was passively answered already :)

Comment: The difference between those two code blocks is that the first one will not generate an `<a>` tag in the output, while the second will. `passHref` is meant to be used when the direct child of `Link` is a React component that wraps an `<a>` tag, so that the `href` can be passed down to it. In all other scenarios, you should just wrap the children of `Link` with an `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

```
passHref - Forces Link to send the href property to its child. Defaults to false
```

When using `<Link>` wrapping a custom component and not an anchor tag, the `<Link>` tag must have the passHref attribute. Without this, the  tag will not have the href attribute, which hurts your site's accessibility and might affect SEO.

[Source](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-custom-component-that-wraps-an-a-tag)